# Difficulty in calling function properly in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a function attached to angular app module through "app.factory" which has certain http requests in it. That function is invoked in the controller and the returned data from function is assigned to a scope variable in controller.

Problem is controller is being executed first and then the http requests in the function are executed due to which the data coming from http request can't be captured into scope variable. How that can be corrected.

```
function resourceapp.factory('dataService', function($http){
  var data = {};
  data.EnterprisePrograms = [];
  data.Resources=[];
  data.Skills=[];
  data.Allocations=[];

  Execution = function($http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/enterpriseProgram')
      .then(function(resources) {
        data.EnterprisePrograms=resources.data;
      });

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/resource')
      .then(function(resources) {
        data.Resources=resources.data;
      });

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/skill')
      .then(function(resources) {
        data.Skills=resources.data;
      });

    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/allocation')
      .then(function(allocation) {
        data.Allocations = allocation.data;
      });
  }

  return data;
});
```

controller

```
resourceapp.controller('AllocationList', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.allocationList = dataService.Allocations;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like :

**In factory :** Create a method to return promise.

```
 resourceapp.factory('dataService', function($http){
    var data = {};

    data.getEnterprisePrograms = function($http){
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/enterpriseProgram');
      }

    data.getResourceData = function($http) {   
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/resource');
      }

    data.getSkillData = function($http) {
       return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/skill');
      }

    data.getAllocationData = function($http) {   
       return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/allocation');
    }

    return data;
});
```

**In Controller**, call the factory method to fetch promise and resolve them with `$q.all()`

```
 resourceapp.controller('AllocationList', function($scope, dataService, $q){
              var allocationPromise = dataService.getAllocationData();
              var skillPromise= dataService.getSkillData();
              // other promise

 $q.all([allocationPromise,skillPromise, ..other promise]).then(function (result) {
              $scope.allocationData = result[0].data;
             $scope.skillData = result[1].data;
              // other data
          })
 });
```

See [this](https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q#qall) for `$q.all()`

Comment: @Founded1898 : you probably right, I updated the answer.

Comment: It still doesn't populates the $scope.allocationList due to execution order @anoop

Comment: @Sakky : what is execution order, I don't see your call (atleast from frontend) dependent on any other call data?

Comment: @anoop: An object needs to be created with all the data from http responses hence all the queries needs to be executed and respective variables should be populated and called into controller. but controller is getting executed first due and at last http requests and executed due to being async.

Comment: @Sakky : In controller through `$q.all()` you have all data in `result` array, now you can assign same data to1 or multiple properties of controller. like = `$scope.data.allocationList = result[index].data` and `$scope.data.resource = result[index].data` . then you finally have all data in single property `$scope.data`, and make a separate boolean flag when all data is loaded. like `$scope.allaDataLoaded = true;`

Answer (score 1):

You could also create a function for each $http.get using promises.

```
EnterprisePrograms = function(){
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/enterpriseProgram')
        .then(function(resources){
            return resources.data;
        });
}
Resources = function(){
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/resource')
    .then(function(resources){
        return resources.data;
    });
}
Skills = function(){
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/skill')
    .then(function(resources){
        return resources.data;
    });
}
Allocations = function(){
    return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/allocation')
    .then(function(allocation){
        return allocation.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: An object with the the results of all the http requests needs to be made